# Is writing as many tests as possible at once a good practice for TDD?

Tags: language-agnostic, tdd

I'm a beginner with TDD; I've just read TDD by example and now I can't seem to stop writing code in a TDD fashion. I've noticed that a lot of the time I'm writing a test, see it fail, correct it, and refactor. And then after some tests I see that there was actually a better way to write the interface all-along which leads me to want to change some of the previous tests.

It obviously makes a lot of code I write a waste of time, so I'm wondering if it is a good practice to write all of the tests at once (or at least try to) in-order to save time? I'm asking because I know it's not the standard way, but is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is "Do you get more finished code done in a given length of time?" It doesn't matter how many times you write it and throw it away if you get more in the end.

As you use tests more, you will get better about figuring out whether a test is good or not. Ask yourself the question, "Does this test help the code somehow?" Does it document how to use the code? Does it check that the code didn't get modified incorrectly when refactoring? Does it test the code works right on the "happy path" and for the kinds of failures that are common?

I would write one test and then one bit of code. You have to decide how much is "one unit" of code but you'll get a feel for it as you do it.

Then I would either update the test to make it better and improve the code to meet those changes OR write another test and update the code to meet that tests requirments.

And just keep on going. One bit of test. One bit of code. It keeps you focused that way.

Don't forget YAGNI. (You ain't gonna need it.) This is the principle that says you write code only for what you need right NOW. Don't write any code for "just in case" or "it's needed later."

Later will come with its own requirements. You will still know how to code it, maybe better because you will have more experience. What you think you will need may (or may not) be what you actually need when you get there.

Writing code too early is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Wonderful answer, but I want to address the first paragraph: If I'll write a bunch of tests first then I'll only write one version of code and not a bunch of other versions which I'll end up deleting. So yes, I think I could write more code in a given length of time. So should I actually write as many tests as possible at the start of the project?

Comment: You have to choose what will allow you to be as efficient as possible. Sometimes you have to keep accurate records and test doing it different ways to see which one is really fastest over time. Don't forget to count all your time, not just the time you are typing.

Comment: Ah I understand. A million thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

"The management question, therefore, is not whether to build a pilot system and throw it away. You will do that. […] Hence plan to throw one away; you will, anyhow."

Fred Brooks, *The Mythical Man-Month*

You're not the only one to come up with better ways to do things after they're done. You should actually plan for it. :)

Comment: Fred Brooks, "The Mythical Man-Month", 20th anniversary edition: "... *Plan to throw one away; you will anyhow.* This I know perceive to be wrong, not because it is too radical, but because it is too simplistic. The biggest mistake ... is that it implicitly assumes the classic sequential or waterfall model of software construction."

Comment: Yes but if you use something like agile programming, the prototype is quickly buried in the changes. If you use a descent version control, by comparing the first check-ins to the finish product, you will see that you did "throw away" most of the first version.